# Subacribing to multiple inboxes using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Looking at the [Create Subscription API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation, I would like to understand if, a single service account user can register for multiple users' calendars in the same request?

The example shows API requests being sent as the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scenario for delegated access to the Graph and application (app-only) access to the graph. For your scenario, you would require to ask for application access and request a Mail.Read permission to get access to multiple mailboxes. Documentation on this can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0
and specifically about this permission here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-14

Comment: Clarification: Calendars.Read app-only permission is required here to access calendars.

Comment: Thanks Peter for catching that.